# route router v4 does not reflect component change with Link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What's wrong with my route structure? Used Link to navigate couldn't see the changes.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <AuthRoute></AuthRoute>
          <Switch>
            <Route path='' component={Home} />
            <Route path='/profile' component={Profile} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/r433m6kvvp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes:

1- Instead of `path=''` (blank path) use `path='/'`.

2- Use `exact` word with `path='/'` otherwise define that in that last, because if you don't use exact then `/` will match with `/profile` or any other route also.

Check the doc for more details about **[exact](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool)** and **[Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch)** and how they work.

Like this:

```
<Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
<Route path='/profile' component={Profile} />
```

or

```
<Route path='/profile' component={Profile} />
<Route path='/' component={Home} />
```

**[Working Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/yj1x5qykmz)**.

Comment: thanks so much! but any clue bout this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474482/auth-route-componentwillmount-or-didmount-did-not-trigger-when-navigate

Comment: what if I want to do redirect in the function? it will cause infinite loop.

Comment: in which function you want to re-direct?

Comment: you just said put the function in both componentWillReceiveProps and componentDidMount right?

Comment: yes, but that re-direct will be based on some condition correct? or always you want to re-direct?

Comment: @Maybank it doesn't matter isn't it? want I want to do is check localstorage, if some key is true then always bring user to a particular page.