# auth route componentWillMount or DidMount did not trigger when navigate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component as 'middleware' where it check for condition and trigger some function, it work when user enter into the page (I mean initial load) or user refreshed the page. But `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount` won't trigger if user enter the path via `<Link>`?

https://codesandbox.io/s/r433m6kvvp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` are the [mounting methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting), not [updating methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating), they will not get called on component re-rendering.

**Solution:**

You need to do one change, put the `BrowserRouter` here:

```
render(<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And use `componentWillReceiveProps` inside Auth component, for initial rendering `componentDidMount` will get called and for each route change `componentWillReceiveProps` will get called, you can execute the function at both the places.

**[Working Code.](https://codesandbox.io/s/j1kvvom73)**

Comment: this is not normal, are people doing auth this way? I've never seen this patern before?